# Create a listview of the database ,columns contains arrays

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, view, cursor

First my English is weak ...
I have created a database contains the array like this:

**_id      >cars      >parts**

**0      >toyota      >part1,part2,part3...**

I use to add in listview Simplecurseradapter class ; it's work

but I want to get array parts to  Textview array and show it row;

I tried use split 
I tried use this code

---

```
    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor)
    {
        LinearLayout linearLayout=(LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.llayout);
        TextView car=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.dictionaryrawTextView2);
        ArrayList<String> partslist=new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("parts")).split(",")));
        TextView parts[]=new TextView[partslist.size()];

        car.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("car")));
        for(int i=0 ;i<partslist.size();i++){
            parts[i]=new TextView(mContext);
            parts[i].setText(partslist.get(i));
            linearLayout.addView(parts[i]);
        }
    }
```

---

It's not work fine .... plz

I waiting you!

**I tried to make like this **

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVotD.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution 
Use

```
getCursor().getString(getCursor().getColumnIndex("a")));
```

Replace

```
mCursor
```

to

getCursor()

Answer (score 0):

you should see what this `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("parts")).split(","))` line gives you as a result.

make it this:

```
String testOutput = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("parts")).split(","));
Log.d("somethinghere", "Parts String: " + testOutput);
```

And see if THAT works properly, and then slowly add the rest of the code to it and see which part fails.

---

However,

Your root problem is that your database is poorly designed, it is not scalable and is not updatable (easily).

You should have 2 tables, 1 being  [ _id, cars ] and another being  [ _id, car_id, part ] (or move 'car_id' out of the 2nd table and have a 3rd 'look up table' that is [ id, car_id, part_id ] ). This would allow you to store a car and associate it with any number of 'parts'. A One-to-Many relationship.

The query for this becomes slightly more complicated, but is at least scalable.

Comment: thanks, the code is return ArrayList of parts ,, but I want to view all strings parts in new TextView every items

Comment: Thanks for your note I found the solution